# DevicePixelRatio doesn't match expectations

Tags: css, screen-resolution

I have monitor with native resolution 3072 width and 1920 height of physical pixels. However I use scaled version (1792 x 1120). I have created a simple site containing div styled with height: 1120px;. Opening site in full screen mode without any browser's headers covers my screen in exactly 100%. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) states:

> The devicePixelRatio of Window interface returns the ratio of the
> resolution in physical pixels to the resolution in CSS pixels for the
> current display device.

So I looked at devTools console and I see that for me window.devicePixelRatio = 2.
And now I wonder if my devicePixelRatio shouldn't be equal 1920/1120 instead of 2? If it really is 2 then my native height resolution should be 2240 physical pixels.

Comment: Which browser are you checking that in?

Comment: In Google chrome

Comment: It's the same for my Pro Display XDR. No matter what resolution I set it to, I always get `2`, unless I set it to its full native resolution (which makes it totally unusable), then I get `1`.

Comment: Yee, it seems that changing resolution scale doesn't impact devicePixelRatio at all (checked both windows and mac). However zooming in/out does.